# Django template NoReverseMatch exception

Tags: django, django-templates, django-views

I'm trying to make a blog in django 1.5. I'm getting this exception message `Reverse for 'blog.views.add_comment post.id' with arguments '(4,)' and keyword arguments '{}' not found.` I can't see where the problem is ocurring. The template code is the following.

```
...
    <!-- post.html -->
       <form action="{% url 'blog.views.add_comment' post.id %}" method="POST">{% csrf_token %}
        <div id="cform">
        Name: {{ form.author }}
        <p>{{ form.body|linebreaks }}</p>
         </div>
        <div id="submit"><input type="submit" value="Submit"></div>
        </form>
...
```

And this is the code from my blog.view.py

```
@render_to('post.html')
def post_detail(request, pk):
    post = Post.objects.get(pk=int(pk))
    comments = Comment.objects.filter(post = post)
    dic = {'post': post, 'user': request.user, 'comments': comments, 'form': CommentForm()}
    dic.update(csrf(request))
    return dic


def add_comment(request, pk):
    """add new comment"""
    p = request.POST

    if p.has_key('body') and p['body']:
        author = 'anonymus'
        if p['author']:
            author = p['author']

        comment = Comment (post=Post.objects.get(pk=pk))
        cf = CommentForm(p, instace = comment)
        cf.fields['author'].required = False

        comment = cf.save(commit = False)
        comment.author = author
        comment.save()
    return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('views.post_detail', args=[pk]))
```

and finally my blog.urls.py

```
urlpatterns = patterns('blog.views',
url(r'^$', 'main'),
...
    url(r'^add_comment/(?P<pk>\d+)/$', 'add_comment'),
)
```

There was a missing 'keyword' is all fixed now thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
{% url 'blog.views.add_comment' post.id %}
```

Comment: And `reverse('views.post_detail', args=[pk])` should probably be `blog.views.post_detail` as well.

Comment: @mariodev Thanks, this makes the parameter to pass through, but I still get the same exception with a variant `Reverse for 'blog.views.add_comment' with arguments '(4,)' and keyword arguments '{}' not found.` (assuming 4 is the pk of the blog post i'm trying to access). Also tried dan-klasson suggestion chaging the current path in reverse to the suggested one, same output.

Comment: @DiegoRomero post the code, where the actual exception is raised. You most probably have a bug in reverse function with add_comment somewhere, but I don't see it in above code.

Comment: @mariodev Hi, thanks, according to django's error it show's that the error is triggered from the template `action="{% url 'blog.views.add_comment' post.id %}"` I also edited the error message. Thanks!